# Generalization of computability to continuous for loops?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, church-turing-thesis, physics, mu-calculus

A computable function, formulated in the sense of mu recursion, can compute a for or do loop over some (possibly infinite) integer range.

I was wondering if a suitable generalization exists that allows the computation of a real-domain function $f$ where $f(x)$ can be calculated given the values of $f(y)$ for all real $y<x$. This seems natural to ask, given that it is relevant if you want to describe e.g. a real-world physical system as an algorithm.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51682/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152915/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: What do you mean by '_$f(x)$ can be calculated given the values of $f(y)$ for all real $y<x$'_?  This is not meaningful without already having some well-defined non-standard notion of a computation that somehow takes uncountably many inputs.

Comment: @NealYoung Indeed, and I'm asking for such a non-standard notion of computation.

Comment: I see, but this latter question is independent of $f$ having a particular form, it's just something like _is there any studied notion of a computation that takes uncountably many inputs_?   Is that what you are intending to ask?  I'm also curious what kind of real-world physical system you'd like to model.. as I'd guess that any such system would have more structure than just that.

Comment: Have you looked at hypercomputation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation#%22Infinite_computational_steps%22_models

Comment: @NealYoung: there are well-defined notions of computation on topological spaces. Cardinality (countable vs. uncountable) plays a very small role in these notions. One can perfectly well compute on spaces like $\mathbb{R}$, and much more complicated ones.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, to clarify, I don't mean inputs from an uncountable space, I mean that a single input contains uncountably many values.  That seems to be what the post requires.  Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, despite claims by several people here, there are models of computation which support computation on topological spaces. The "countable vs. uncountable" distinction is a red herring, arising from being familiar only with notions of computation on discrete spaces. A good introductory text on the topic of computable analysis is Klaus Weihrauch's [Comuptable analysis – an introduction](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-56999-9).

Your idea is very closely related to the principle of **open induction**, which states: if an *open* subset $S \subseteq [0,1]$ satisfies $(\forall y \in [0,1].\, y < x \Rightarrow y \in S) \Rightarrow x \in S$ then $S = [0,1]$. In words: if an open $S$ has the property "if all numbers smaller than $x$ are in $S$ then so is $x$" then $S$ is the whole interval.

It is easy enough to speculate a functional version of open induction, which we could call **open recursion** (caveat – I am speaking off the top of my head here): given a map $$h : \Pi (x : [0,1]) \, (f : [0,x) \to \mathbb{R}) .\, \Sigma (\epsilon > 0) (g : [0, x + \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}) . \, g{\restriction}_{[0,x)} = f$$ there is a unique map $\mathcal{O} h : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$
\mathcal{O} h (t) = h \, t \, ((\mathcal{O} h){\restriction}_{[0,t)})
$
for all $t : [0,1]$, where $f{\restriction}_{[0,t)}$ is the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[0,t)$.

The principle of open induction holds in classical mathematics (exercise), from which it follows that open recursion is valid as well (another exercise). That is, the notation $\mathcal{O} \, h$ is well-defined for any $h$.

Now, the interesting question is whether we can *compute* with open recursion. In [An induction principle over real numbers](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01376054/document) explained how to compute with open induction. I am fairty sure that her method can be adapted to open recursion, but it would take more time to write up the details than I can invest in answering this question. I would be very interested to hear, however, if my hunch is correct.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no modelizations of physical systems with functions of infinitely many independent variables (which would be your generalization of *complete induction*, I guess).

Instead, models that predict the current value of a continuous signal based on previous "samples" (and some smoothness property) evoke ordinary or partial differential equations. These are solved by analytical techniques when possible using symbolic integration, for which we do have discrete algorithms, or by numerical methods, for which we also have discrete algorithms.